# How can I use nHibernate to get a small subset of object properties for list view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, nhibernate

I am using ASP.NET-MVC and nHibernate for the first time. Great tools, but big learning curve!

I have a list view of objects that are quite large (each has about 60 properties). In the list view I am only using about 10 of these properties. Performance is not too bad, but it seems a waste to fully hydrate these objects. What is the recommended practice?

I tried using HQL to select fewer properties, but it seems like it won't partially hydrate an object. I also tried making property on the main object that was a header class with the list view properties, but I couldn't seem to get it mapped properly. I think this should be easy but I've really been struggling with it.

**EDIT:** 
I kept coming back to this because I knew Anton had given me the answer and I just couldn't see it.

There are three things you need to do:

1. Make an object with the properties you want.
2. Make a mapping file to import this object.

   `<`hibernate-mapping
     xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2"
     namespace="Core.Entities"
     assembly="Core"
     default-access="property">
         `<`import class="RequestHeader" /`>`
   `<`/hibernate-mapping>
3. If you are using HQL, your object must contain a constructor with all the properties, in the same order, as your select new statement. If you use the Criteria API, you don't need to do this.

   ```
   public IList<RequestHeader> ListAll()
   {
       using (ISession session = GetSession())
       {
           using (ITransaction tx = session.BeginTransaction())
           {
               IList<RequestHeader> results = session.CreateCriteria(typeof (Request), "r")
                   .CreateCriteria("Requestor", "req", JoinType.InnerJoin)
                   .CreateCriteria("r.Grant", "g", JoinType.InnerJoin)
                   .SetProjection(Projections.ProjectionList()
                       .Add(Projections.Property("r.Id"), "Id")
                       .Add(Projections.Property("r.Status"), "Status")
                       .Add(Projections.Property("r.SubmissionDate"), "SubmissionDate")
                       .Add(Projections.Property("req.Name"), "Requestor")
                       .Add(Projections.Property("g.Number"), "Number"))
                   .SetResultTransformer(Transformers.AliasToBean(typeof (RequestHeader)))
                   .SetMaxResults(10000)
                   .List<RequestHeader>();
               tx.Commit();
               return results;
           }
       }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

60 properties is too much. See [Component mapping](https://www.hibernate.org/hib_docs/nhibernate/1.2/reference/en/html/components.html).

As for selecting a subset of properties, see [this](https://www.hibernate.org/hib_docs/nhibernate/1.2/reference/en/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-select): you need a `select new` HQL construct. Be aware, though, that you need an appropriate constructor and that an object you'll get cannot be saved back to the DB.

Comment: Thanks. I had read both your links, but was at a point where the more I read, the more confused I got. I am finally starting to grok the ORM concept though. I recommend the "Summer of nHibernate" videos by Steve Bohlen to anyone getting started.